# How to combine two objects with rxjs

Tags: javascript, rxjs

How to combine two objects with rxjs
For example, I have

```
const users$ = Rx.Observable.of([
    {id: 1, name: 'Arthur', lang: 'en'}, 
    {id: 2, name: 'Asset', lang: 'ru'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Steve', lang: 'en'}
])
const months$ = Rx.Observable.of({
    ru: ['Январь', 'Февраль'],
    en: ['January', 'February']
})
```

Must be at the output

```
[
    { 
        months: ['Январь', 'Февраль']
        user: 'Asset
    }
    { 
        months: ['January', 'February']
        user: 'Arthur
    }
    { 
        months: ['January', 'February']
        user: 'Steve
    }
]
```

We must use only rxjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more like an array operation no need to use rxjs really

```js
Observable.zip(users$,month$).map(([users,months])=>
  users.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
   acc.push({user:curr.name,month:months[curr.lang]})
   return acc;
   },[])
).subscribe()
```